# spring-integration (SI), deploy as EAR

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-integration, spring-jms

I just recently started learning about [spring-integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) since I need to replace the a MDB(J2EE) application.

The application is composed of mostly MDB which does, splitting, aggregating and scheduling. Which, I think is the perfect criteria to use spring-integration.

I tried out some JMS examples and tried to deploy it but could not figure out how to use the jms-inbound-gateway to replace the MDB.

Is there a way to do this? Or is the only option is still to use MDB and calling the spring-integration service from the MDB's onMessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a message-driven-channel-adapter instead of an inbound gateway.

With Spring Integration, gateways are for two-way (request/reply) integraton; channel adapters are for one way integration; more like MDBs.

If you need to send some other JMS message downstream, use an outbound channel adapter later in the flow.

It's unusual to keep the MDBs, but you can do it if you really want to, and send a message to an integration flow.

Comment: Thanks, @Gary actually, I am not particularly inclined to use MDB strictly, but the reason I thought of using MDB is there is this corporate rule to always deploy via EAR. And the only way I thought of having SI deployed as EAR (not stand-alone) is to use J2EE's MDB. Do you have other suggestion to deploy this via J2EE ear?

Comment: You can deploy it as a simple WAR within the EAR, no need for the additional complexity of an MDB - you don't have to provide a Web interface (but you can - for example you might have a simple `@Controller` to enable control/monitoring of your app using a `<control-bus/>`).